# How to put ticks inside geom_bar() and offset geom_point() (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a chart in which `geom_bar()` and `geom_point()` were combined. This worked well. But now I have two more questions about the appearance:

(1) Is there a way to insert "ticks" inside the graphic (like in picture 2)?
(2) Some of the values are the same, which causes the points to overlap (& some are therefore no longer visible). Is there a way to offset the points?

Thank you, here my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=data1, aes(Question, HG, fill = yes_share), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(Question, yes_share, color = factor(party), size=3)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#efc100","#ff9100", "#61b5a5","#3a8bc1", "#a0a000", "#66cc00","#825000", "#726F44","#dd0e0e","#0a7228", "#a7c1a8")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(col1, col2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.1, color="black") ,
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank() ,
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank() ,
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank() ,
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

How it looks
[image: How it looks]

How it should look
[image: How it should look]

Comment: If you want answers that show you how exactly to do it in your situation you should provide your data so we can recreate the plot. 
For the ticks you could just insert line or segments at the appropriate position and length for example with `geom_segment()`.
The overlap issue could be solved by adding and alpha value to your points, which would make them partially see-through or you could add jitter with `position = "jitter"` to your points and adjust the intensity as needed.

Comment: Consider using `geom_col` rather than geom_bar(stat = "identity"). Tick marks could be added with `geom_point` or another geom. Consider `ggforce::geom_sina` (or `geom_jitter`) to prevent overlap.